# Differential equation substitution $z=\frac y x\implies z'=xz'+z$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I'm reading book about differential equations and there is said that you can substitute $z=\dfrac yx$ and that means $z'=xz'+z$.

How this is possible?

Comment: I cant write those upper "code marks".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $z = \frac{y}{x}$ then $y(x) = x\cdot z(x)$ - the important part here is that $x$ is your independent variable and both $y$ and $z$ depend on it. Hence when we take $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} (x\cdot z(x))$ we have to use the product rule on the right hand side)

\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} (x\cdot z(x)) = x\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}x} + \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}x}\cdot z(x) = x\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}x} + z(x).
\end{equation}